# How to observe Core Data persistent store changing between containing app and extension

Tags: ios, core-data, ios-app-extension

I setup the sqlite file in the shared app group, both containing app and app extension can write entities to the store. Here is the problem: when both containing app and extension are running in the same time, when I add new entity from the extension, how to let the containing app known the store has been changed and let it perform refreshing? or vice versa?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28197360/action-expension-and-sharing-core-data/28221033#28221033

Comment: Thanks, Tom. Got some inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a Swift project: https://github.com/cxa/AppExtensionCommunicator

In short, you can handle notifications posted by `CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter()`, this type of notification can be delivered between extension and its containing app. Check the project for detail.